# Function for fetched image will not re-iterate [Simple HTML DOM Parser]

Tags: php, jquery, html

As the title states. I have a function, which runs when I want it to.

Problem is that it only runs once, and I want it to run until it manages to find the image I'm looking for (since all `example.com/id` doesn't exist). The `var_dump` does not return anything, neither does an `echo` or a `print_r`.

Let's just assume this runs on page load.

```
<div class="echo">

<?php

include('advanced_html_dom.php');
getDataLOL();

function getDataLOL() {

    $randArt = mt_rand(0, 100000);
    $url = "http://example.com/".$randArt;
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    // Find all images
    foreach($html->find('img.example') as $element) {
        if(empty($element)) {
            getDataLOL(); //Re-iterate the function
        } else {
            var_dump($element); //Or show me what's been fetched
        }
    }
}

?>

</div>
```

Any tips or help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to recur at all--`advanced_html_dom.php` should handle parsing of the entire document.

For example, check out this example:

```
include('advanced_html_dom.php');

function get_image() {

    $url  = "http://blackwood.io/slow-blinking-cat-behavior-no-consensus/";
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    // Find all images
    foreach ($html->find('img') as $element) {
        var_dump($element->attributes['src']);
    }
    
}

get_image();
```

This works fine--it dumps the image srcs. Its quite possible the URL you are hitting uses JavaScript to generate the image, because there'd be no other likely reason I can think of the image wouldn't be there on load.

Also, try `var_dump` on the `$html` variable, that might give you a better indication of what the HTML page looks like on load, or better yet, turn off JavaScript and confirm that the page returns anything at all.

---

**EDIT:**

Let me clarify, I think its unclear whether or not you're actually including the library and making the call to `file_get_html` successfully. That aside, I think there's a simpler way you can achieve recursion without calling the function itself. Here's a modified version of your code, using a site that returns a random word, and instead of our condition being that there's an image on the page, its that the last letter of the word ends with an 's'.

```
include('advanced_html_dom.php');

function get_word() {

    $url  = "http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php";
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    return $html->find('body')[0]->plaintext();
}

function ends_with_s($word) {
    return substr($word, -1) == 's';
}

function find_word() {
    
    $words = array();

    $html  = get_word();

    while (!ends_with_s($html)) {
        
        array_push($words, $html);

        $html = get_word();

    }


    echo "These words didn't end with 's': <pre>" . implode(", ", $words) . "</pre> \n";

    echo "This was the first word to end with 's': <pre>" .  $html . "</pre> \n";

}

find_word();
```

As you can see, by using a while loop and resetting the `$html` variable, our condition is evaluated each time through our `ends_with_s` function in the while loop. Just as a proof of concept, I've shown how you might gather the data that failed the condition as well.

Here's an example output:

> These words didn't end with 's':
>
> `unfavorably, parietosphenoid, dramshop, decidual, systematist`
>
> This was the first word to end with 's':
>
> `degreeless`

Comment: The problem is that the id is randomly generated (example.com/123456), and not all ids contain an article, just brings you to the front page. Therefor I need to re-iterate the function till it finds an article which contains the content I'm searching for.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump` on the `$html` var to make sure that you're even getting the first article?